# How to revert back Mat-Select's selected value for a specific option?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, dropdown

I am using `mat-select`, and my requirement is to revert back the selection for a specific value of `mat-select`'s `mat-option`.

For example, Have a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-wzayca?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Here `mat-select` has three options; when I select `Canada`, it should revert back to the value I've selected previously.

```
  onCountryChange($event) {
    const oldIndex = this.countries.indexOf(this.selectedCountry);
    if ($event.value.short === 'CA') {
      this.selectedCountry = this.countries[oldIndex];
    } else {
      this.selectedCountry = $event.value;
    }
  }
```

I can see that the value is getting updated from the `json` besides the `mat-select`. However, the `mat-select` is not updating the selected option.

So far I tried setting value using `FormControl`, `setTimeout`, by attaching just `short` property of the object instead of attaching entire object with `mat-option` ([this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-chhn11?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)  for reference). But couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use **mat-select-trigger**.
This is a due to the mat-select using OnPush change detection. You may be interested in using **mat-select-trigger**. Try that and let me know if it works for you.

```
<mat-select name="countryVaraible" [value]="selectedCountry" placeholder="Country" (selectionChange)="onCountryChange($event)">
    <mat-select-trigger>{{selectedCountry.full}}</mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">
      {{country.full}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```